# How to check the type of a non-primitive variable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I've had an issue for a long time that I can't find how to resolve. I would like to check the type of a variable: if it's one type do something, else do something else.

In this example I use `typeof` (which is of course not possible) just to give an idea of what I would like to do.

I would like to render a different component based on the type of button.

```
type Type01 = {
  path: string;
  label: string;
};

type ComponentTestType = {
  button: Type01 | "default" | JSX.Element;
};

export function ComponentTest({ button }: ComponentTestType) {
  if (typeof button === "default") {
    //do something
  } else if (typeof button === Type01) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking since `a` is undefined. You should look into [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) and post a question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: This depends strongly on `OtherExempleType`.  Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can check for the value or typeof and TypeScript will narrow it down correctly.

```js
if (obj.a === 'default') {
    ...
} else if (typeof obj.a === 'number') {
    ...
} else {
    // OtherExempleType
}
```